# UIWebView horizontal bounce not working

Tags: ios, uiview, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I am trying to get my UIWebView to bounce Horizontally, it already bounces vertically but its just not doing the Horizontal bounce.

I add the UIWebView like this

```
// pass data off to the correct view to be used
    lpViewController = [[LPViewController alloc] init];
    lpViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, infoBarHeight, lpViewController.view.bounds.size.width, lpViewController.view.bounds.size.height);

    lpViewController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

    lpViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


    [self.view insertSubview:lpViewController.view belowSubview:actionTabBar];
```

Then inside lpViewController viewDidLoad method I have tried to get the horizontal bounce like this.

```
for (UIView *subview in [lockPositionsWebView subviews]) {
    if ([subview isMemberOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
        [(UIScrollView *)subview setAlwaysBounceVertical:YES];
        [(UIScrollView *)subview setAlwaysBounceHorizontal:YES];
    }
}

lockPositionsWebView.scrollView.bounces = NO;

lockPositionsWebView.scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = YES;
lockPositionsWebView.scrollView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = YES;
```

but thats not working either, it gets the Vertical bounce but not the Horizontal...

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get your `UIWebView` to bounce both horizontally and vertically, set the `bounces` property of the scrollview to `YES`.

Change your code above to:

```
lockPositionsWebView.scrollView.bounces = YES;

lockPositionsWebView.scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = YES;
lockPositionsWebView.scrollView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = YES;
```

The `bounces` property must be `YES` for `alwaysBounceVertical` and `alwaysBounceHorizontal` to work.

See Apple's doco for `alwaysBounceHorizontal`:

> A Boolean value that determines whether bouncing always occurs when
>   horizontal scrolling reaches the end of the content view.
>   If this property is set to YES **and bounces is YES**, horizontal dragging is
>   allowed even if the content is smaller than the bounds of the scroll
>   view. The default value is NO.