# iOS: UIWebView horizontal scrolling doesn't work

Tags: ios, uiwebview, scroll

I am displaying a local html file in a UIWebView object. Horizontal scrolling doesn't work but vertical works well. How to solve this issue?

My trial code:

```
self.webView.scrollView.delegate = self;
self.webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
[self.webView.scrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:YES];
self.webView.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1000, 1000);
```

Comment: Is the webView or scrollView created in interface builder?

Comment: yes, it's created in IB

Comment: Your code works fine in iOS7 simulator. Are you sure that your web view is fully visible?

Comment: Try this Answer ya Abu Adam :))
http://stackoverflow.com/a/17359406/1783065

Comment: Do you have the IBOutlet's for you webView and scrollView connected to your NIB?

Comment: Yes, it's in place and fully showing

Comment: @Tahan Now it is bouncing but still cutting the edge without scrolling along the document width

Comment: Please verify if its not coming from the HTML being rendered. May be the overflow-x property of the body has been set to hidden. Also make sure that you are not using a percentage layout for the HTML. Use fixed width layout instead.